# Counting multiple unique values within same key in Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I am trying to keep track of the amount of times four specific string values show up within the same key.

The problem is, I am having a hard time adding multiple counters. The first counter works and tracks the first condition, but the next condition within the if/else statement prevents the initial and every condition from there on after, from adding up properly.  The data is coming from a `Promise.all` that contains multiple URLs.

Here is my code:

```
const urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=1',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=2',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=3',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=4',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=5',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=6',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=7',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=8',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=9',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=10',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=11',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=12'
]


function getLanguages() {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
    fetch(`${url}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(obj => obj.forEach(function(val) {
      var rubyCounter = 0
      var cssCounter = 0
      var htmlCounter = 0
      var jsCounter = 0
      if (val.language === "Ruby") {
        rubyCounter++;
        console.log(rubyCounter);
      }

    })))
  )
}

getLanguages();
```

`rubyCounter` will return `235`, which is the correct amount, but if I add anymore conditions, it is like the true/false condition running through the same key throws everything off.  I may be missing something glaring, but I was curious to see what you guys thought.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result you get from `response.json()` is not JSON. Calling that function interprets the data of the response as JSON, parses it and returns a JavaScript Object. JSON ist  a string based representation of data, and has to be parse before you can traverse, iterator, ... it.

Comment: For this code `rubyCounter` will always be `1` if it is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code `rubyCounter` will always be `1` if it is logged, because those counter is always initialized within the calllback.

You would need ot move the dfinition of those counter to the root of `getLanguages`.

And instead of using multible variables for each counter I would use an Object and for each language you want to count you have a property.

```js
const urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=1',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=2',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=3',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=4',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=5',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=6',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=7',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=8',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=9',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=10',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=11',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=12'
]


function getLanguages() {
  let counter = {
    ruby: 0,
    html: 0
  }

  return Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
      fetch(`${url}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(obj => obj.forEach(function(val) {
        /*var rubyCounter = 0
        var cssCounter = 0
        var htmlCounter = 0
        var jsCounter = 0*/
        if (val.language === "Ruby") {
          counter.ruby++;
        } else if (val.language === "HTML") {
          counter.html++;
        }

      }))))
    .then(() => {
      console.dir(counter)
    })
}

getLanguages();
```

If you want to cound all languages then it is even simpler:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=1',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=2',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=3',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=4',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=5',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=6',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=7',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=8',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=9',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=10',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=11',
  'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=12'
]


function getLanguages() {
  let counter = {}

  return Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
      fetch(`${url}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(obj => obj.forEach(function(val) {
        if( val.language ) {
          counter[val.language] = counter[val.language] || 0
          counter[val.language]++
        }
      }))))
    .then(() => {
      console.dir(counter)
    })
}

getLanguages();
```

Comment: Beautifully executed!  Worked like a charm!  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is working for you:

```
const urls = [
            'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=1',
            'https://api.github.com/users/TylerP33/repos?page=2'
        ]

        var counters = {};
        function getLanguages() {
            return Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
                fetch(`${url}`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => json.forEach(function (val) {
                        if (!counters[val.language])
                            counters[val.language] = 0;

                        counters[val.language]++;

                    }))
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log(counters);
                    });
            }));
        }

        getLanguages();
```

Comment: This works amazing!  Thanks a ton!  Didn't even know that was possible :D.

Both answers worked great, so I am not sure who gets the check mark... :/